# Django timezone mess

Tags: django, timezone

I'm working on a localized Django app with a simple forum. Some posts' timestamps show up as if they were posted 7 hours earlier. What's weird is that it happens to some users, sometimes (a user may post once and it's OK, posts again and it's wrong).

settings.py:

```
TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Prague'
LANGUAGES =  ( ('cs-cz', _('Czech')), )
DATABASE_ENGINE = 'sqlite3'
```

model:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Running on Apache with mod_wsgi.

Comment: Found something that may be related to this but I don't understand why the TIME_ZONE setting isn't always taking priority: http://serverfault.com/questions/26248/what-could-cause-apaches-time-timezone-to-change-intermittently

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As referenced in other post you cite, see:

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ApplicationIssues#Timezone%5Fand%5FLocale%5FSettings

The issue is when you have multiple applications running in same server process which want different timezone settings. This is because TZ is a global process environment. Which ever application got to set it last will take precedence over all the others.

Use daemon mode of mod_wsgi and run any Python web applications which require different timezone settings to other applications in their own daemon process group. That way they will not interfere with each other.